# Xcode Designer: How Do I Create 2 Sliding Selector Controls?

Tags: iphone, xcode, interface-builder

[image: sample screenshot]

Hi,
I want to list for ex. speechers in an organization. Let's say a schedule. I've seen a couple apps in AppStore and liked this most. How do we create such controls? Like select the date then the place of speech. Those two don't have to be dependent.
I couldn't see a control like this in Xcode designer.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would have to write your own control. Something like that could be a `UIScrollView` set to paging mode that gets its 3D effect from some neatly positioned gradients. Interface Builder won't help you much (if at all) with this task.

Comment: That's reasonable, but the gradients make auto-align? I mean, can I make controls sit in screen after scroll? Like in pickers.

Comment: You would probably need more than one view: one container view that holds both the scroll view and another view that contains the gradients (which you could draw with `CAGradientLayer`).